# Identifying freemarker files from the browser

Tags: freemarker

I've seen some php templating products allow you to identify which template is rendering a specific piece of content by turning on a "debug mode". When this mode is active, each template is outlined by a (purple) box, and the path to the template used is printed in the top corners of the box.

Can this be done in freemarker?

Answer (score 1):

Where the framework calls `Template.process(..., Writer)`, it can insert such markers into the `Writer`. FreeMarker itself doesn't try to do such things, as it can't have any idea where is it safe to insert such markers. (With the `auto_include`-ing something like `<!-- Template: ${.template_name} -->` you can achieve something similar, but I think it's too dangerous.)